# spring property resolution from a spring expression

Tags: spring, spring-el

I want to resolve a property and specify the name of the property using a Spel expression. If I do this

```
<property name="host" value="#{T(...Constants).SINK_PROP_HOST}" />
```

the value gets resolved correctly to `sink.host` which is the value of this constant. Taking it a step further

```
<property name="host" value="${#{T(...Constants).SINK_PROP_HOST}}" />
```

This doesn't works. Any ideas how I can make it work. Essentially it should function the same as

```
<property name="host" value="${sink.host}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, because properties are resolved before SpEL (you can do it the other way around).

This works...

```
public class Foo {

    public static final String FOO = "foo.prop";

}


<util:properties id="props">
    <prop key="foo.prop">bar</prop>
</util:properties>

<bean id="xx" class="foo.Bar">
    <property name="foo" value="#{props[T(foo.Foo).FOO]}"/>
</bean>
```

You can, of course, load your "props" bean from a file.